# Java image sampling functions analogues in C#

Tags: java, c#

I'm currently trying to port an image editing application from Java to C# and I've run into the issue with the following methods from **java.awt.image.BandedSampleModel** package:

- int getSample(int x, int y, int band, int value)
- void setSample(int x, int y, int band, int value)

Original Java code:

```
    public int getSample(int x, int y, int band)
    {
        return image.getRaster().getSample(x, y, band);
    }

    public void setSample(int x, int y, int band, int value)
    {
        image.getRaster().setSample(x, y, band, value);
    }
```

The questions are following:

1. What does actually `getSample` and and `setSample` methods do? As far as I understand, they are used to get and set the value (sum of R+G+B) of the pixel in **(x, y)** position. What does 'int band' is included in method's signature?
2. As far as I know, there is no analogue functions in default C# API. If so, how should these function be rewritten on C# to have the same signature and behavior?

Code examples are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. After looking on the usages of these function in Java application, I've found out that 'band' parameter can be in range of [0,2]. This parameter specifies the RGB channel number (0 – Red, 1 – Greed, 2 – Blue).
2. As I've managed to find out the purpose of this methods, It became clear how can I rewrite them. I've already ported the application successfully, both methods (on C# and Java) have the same behavior.

   ```
   public int getSample(int x, int y, int band)
   {
       //return image.getRaster().getSample(x, y, band);
       var pixelColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);
       switch (band)
       {
           case 0: return pixelColor.R;
           case 1: return pixelColor.G;
           case 2: return pixelColor.B;
       }
       throw new ArgumentException(nameof(band));
   }

   public void setSample(int x, int y, int band, int value)
   {
       //image.getRaster().setSample(x, y, band, value);
       var oldColor = image.GetPixel(x, y);
       Color newColor;
       switch (band)
       {
           case 0:
               newColor = Color.FromArgb(255, value, oldColor.G, oldColor.B);
               break;
           case 1:
               newColor = Color.FromArgb(255, oldColor.R, value, oldColor.B);
               break;
           case 2:
               newColor = Color.FromArgb(255, oldColor.R, oldColor.G, value);
               break;
           default:
               throw new ArgumentException(nameof(band));
       }
       image.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
   }
   ```